# Replace characters in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, substitution

I have a data.frame

```
Client1 Client2 Client3
3        1        9
6        2        19
23       7        20
45       102      101
55       NA       102
61       NA       NA
```

and another data.frame which has

```
number       date 
1        02.11.2018  
2        03.11.2018        
3        04.11.2018        
4        05.11.2018      
...      ....       
102       12.01.2019
```

the idea is to subtitude numbers in first data.frame with dates in the second one
and to get:

```
Client1          Client2             Client3
04.11.2018        04.11.2018         04.11.2018
04.11.2018        04.11.2018         04.11.2018
04.11.2018        04.11.2018         04.11.2018
04.11.2018        04.11.2018         04.11.2018
04.11.2018        NA                 04.11.2018
04.11.2018        NA                 NA
```

dates are not correct, its an example.
I would be appreciate for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Additionally, please show your attempt and where you failed. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use *match*:

```
# example data
df1 <- read.table(text = "Client1 Client2 Client3
3        1        9
6        2        19
23       7        20
45       102      101
55       NA       102
61       NA       NA", header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "number       date 
1        02.11.2018  
2        03.11.2018        
3        04.11.2018        
4        05.11.2018      
102       12.01.2019", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# loop through columns, use match
data.frame(lapply(df1, function(i)
  df2$date[ match(i, df2$number) ]
  ))

#      Client1    Client2    Client3
# 1 04.11.2018 02.11.2018       <NA>
# 2       <NA> 03.11.2018       <NA>
# 3       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 4       <NA> 12.01.2019       <NA>
# 5       <NA>       <NA> 12.01.2019
# 6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your two dataframes are called `Clients` and `Dates`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Clients %>% 
  gather(everything(), key = Client, value = number) %>% 
  left_join(Dates, by = c("number" = "number")) %>% 
  select(Client, date) %>% 
  spread(key = Client, value = date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @zx8754's example data, you can also try:

```
library(qdap)
as.data.frame(apply(df1, 2, lookup, df2))
# output
#     Client1    Client2    Client3
# 1 04.11.2018 02.11.2018       <NA>
# 2       <NA> 03.11.2018       <NA>
# 3       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 4       <NA> 12.01.2019       <NA>
# 5       <NA>       <NA> 12.01.2019
# 6       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```